# NSOperationQueue does not cancel (remove) operations

Tags: nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I'm looking for a means to handle separate but related NSURLRequest and thought that I could add them to an NSOperationQueue and then manage them (run the request or not based on http status code - if the status code is 200 they can run, if not, stop all of them as the url string needs to be appended).

In my test code below I suspend the OQ to stop the processing of NSURLRequest (represented here by some public RSS feeds) but continue to the request to the OQ. I get the right number of operations (4). After adding all request to the OQ I then check to see if it has been suspended and if so, cancel all the operations.That works, at least the check if it has been suspended.

When I do a count check after canceling the operations I still get 4 but was expecting less (and hoping for 0). I'm using NSURLConnection to get the rss data in a NSObject subclass.

I understand from the docs that NSOQ will not remove an operation until it has reported that it is finished. (Is there a way to see this report?) 
*You cannot directly remove an operation from a queue after it has been added. An operation remains in its queue until it reports that it is finished with its task. Finishing its task does not necessarily mean that the operation performed that task to completion. An operation can also be canceled. Canceling an operation object leaves the object in the queue but notifies the object that it should abort its task as quickly as possible.*

NSURLConnection doesn't have a willStart or similar delegate method so I can't track that but my feeling is the second RSS feed is in some sort of start process and that would explain why it is still in there. But I log the connectionDidFinishLoading delegate and so the first task is completed, so I was expecting at least that to be gone.

So my question is twofold.
1. If I nil out NSOQ, does that eliminate the operations within it? And what danger is there if one of those operations is in process - crash, hanging the app, etc?
2. Is there a way to cancel a NSURLConnection that is in process? (Assuming that the answer to 1 is yes, you are in the danger zone).

Here's my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    connectionManager* myConnectionManager = [[connectionManager alloc] init];
    NSOperationQueue* operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

    NSMutableArray* arrAddedOperations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


    NSArray* arrFeeds = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_topstories.rss", @"http://hosted.ap.org/lineups/USHEADS-rss_2.0.xml?SITE=RANDOM&SECTION=HOME",  @"http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/topNews", @"http://newsrss.bbc.co.uk/rss/newsonline_world_edition/americas/rss.xml", nil];

    //add operations to operation queue
    for(int i=0; i<arrFeeds.count; i++) {

        NSInvocationOperation* rssOperation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc]
                                               initWithTarget: myConnectionManager
                                               selector:@selector(runConnection:)
                                               object:[arrFeeds objectAtIndex:i]];

        //check to put a suspension on the OQ
        if (i>1) {
            operationQueue.suspended = YES;
        }

        [operationQueue addOperation:rssOperation];
        [arrAddedOperations addObject:[arrFeeds objectAtIndex:i]];

        //incremental count to see operations being added to the queue - should be 4
        NSLog(@"This is the number of operations added to the queue:%i", [operationQueue operationCount]);

    }


    if (operationQueue.suspended) {

        //restart the OQ so we can cancel all the operations
        operationQueue.suspended = NO;

        //kill all the operations
        [operationQueue cancelAllOperations];

        //count to see how many operations are left
        NSLog(@"OQ has been suspended and operations canclled. The operation count should be 0\nThe operation count is %i", [operationQueue operationCount]);

    }

}
```

from NSURLConnection class

```
- (void) runConnection : (NSString*) strURL  {

    NSURLRequest* urlRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
    self.myConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self startImmediately:NO];

    [self.myConnection setDelegateQueue:self.myQueue];
    [self.myConnection start];

    self.myConnection = nil;

}




#pragma mark - NSURLConnection Delegates



- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

    NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {

    NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
    NSLog(@"%@", [NSNumber numberWithInteger:httpResponse.statusCode]);

}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {

    self.strReponse = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    //NSLog(@"%@", self.strReponse);


}

- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    NSLog(@"task finished");
    NSDictionary* dictUserInfo = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  @"Display Data", @"Action",
                                  self.strReponse, @"Data",
                                  nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"avc" object:self userInfo:dictUserInfo];   
}
```

Edit: I don't need to save these operations as I am storing the incoming request in a mutable array and which just create a new OQ once they have been appended. I just want to make sure they are cancelled and not leaving the app in a fragile state.